# Can the initialization order of class fields in VB.NET be influenced by references to other fields?

Tags: vb.net, field, initialization-order

Take this sample code:

```
Class Foo
    ReadOnly name As String

    Public Sub New(name As String, dependentUpon As Foo)
        Me.name = name
        Console.Write("{0} created. ", name)
        Console.WriteLine("Dependent upon {0}.", If(dependentUpon IsNot Nothing,
                                                    dependentUpon.Name,
                                                    "nothing"))
    End Sub
End Class

Class Bar
    ReadOnly dependent As New Foo("Dependent", independent)  ' <-- !!!
    ReadOnly independent As New Foo("Independent", Nothing)
End Class
```

The output of `New Bar()` is:

```
Dependent created. Dependent upon nothing.
Independent created. Dependent upon nothing.
```

It seems fields are initialized in the same order as they appear in the source code, which (a) leads to an unexpected result, and (b) seems a little puzzling, given that one is normally not permitted to read from uninitialized variables in .NET, yet that seems to be working fine above.

I would've expected VB.NET to be smart enough to initialize referenced fields first, and only then those that reference it; i.e. I'd have liked to see this output instead:

```
Independent created. Dependent upon nothing.
Dependent created. Dependent upon Independent.
```

Does someone know a way how to get VB.NET to behave like that instead, without simply having to swap the declaration order of `dependent` and `independent` inside class `Bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are always initialized in the order they're declared.

The restriction against accessing uninitialized variables applies only to **local** variables, not fields.  (that would be too hard to enforce)

Comment: Note: this is defined by the CLI and is language independent.

Comment: @Richard: That's actually not correct.  A compiler could turn all fields into `Lazy<T>`s, for example.

Comment: @SLacks: But then the fields would still be initialised in order, but that would be the initialisation of the `Lazy<T>` itself. I did consider a language doing something clever with something like inner types to achieve for fields what F# does for curry-able functions... but in the end a single type still initialises in order.

Comment: Yes, but the initializers that _you wrote_ wouldn't.